# Verify a proof by contradiction: If $f$ and $f\circ g$ are one-to-one, does it follow that $g$ is one-to-one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm attempting to prove this proposition using a proof by contradiction, but I'm not sure I all my statement hold. Specifically, how can I be sure the $5$th statement valid?

1. A function is one-to-one iff $f(a) = f (b)$ implies that $a = b$ for all $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f$.
2. Assume that $g$ is not one-to-one, namely if $f$ and $f \circ g$ are one-to-one then $g$ is not one to one.
3. Given the definition of a one-to-one function $f$ and $f \circ g$ can be written as: $f(a) = f (b)$ $\implies$
   $a = b$ and $f \circ g(a) = f \circ g(b)$ $\implies$ $a
    = b$
4. Using the definition of a function composition this can be written as $f (g(a)) = f (g(b))$ $\implies$ $a
    = b$
5. For this composition to be one-to-one $g(a) = g(b)$ must be true, which means that $a = b$ and $g$ is a one-to-one function by definition which is a contradiction since it was assumed to not be.
6. Therefore if $f$ and $f \circ g$ are one-to-one, it follows that $g$ is one-to-one.

Comment: i think the direct path would be easier, i.e from the definiton of 1-1 and the given conditions the g 1-1 follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flaw in your proof. You did not show that g is a 1-1 function in (5). You were very close, but not quite. Also, your proof is just confusing, and I see no reason to use a proof by contradiction here. Also, where do your functions live? I'm going to assume they are from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are 1-1. We want to show that $g(x)$ is 1-1. To do some, let $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ with $g(a)=g(b)$. Then $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$. since $f(g(x))$ is 1-1, $a=b$, so $g(x)$ is 1-1.

Comment: How do you tell when a direct proof is better than an an indirect proof?

Comment: @NickGilpin a direct proof is always better (and preferable), an indirect proof is used when a direct proof is either very difficult (or impossible?).

Comment: That is a good question. There isn't exactly an easy way to tell that though. One thing though, then contradiction you were trying to derive was with the statement you were trying to prove, so in your attempt to write a proof by contradiction, you ended up doing a direct proof(in this way, EVERY direct proof can be done as a proof by contradiction. It is not clear that the converse holds though.) When this happens, a direct proof is better. Proofs by contradiction are nice when it is easier to work with the negation of the statement you want to prove than to work with your assumptions.